# Impossible to uninstall GIT on MAC MOJAVE

Tags: git, uninstallation

I'm trying to completly remove git from my MacOS Mojave.
I've tried every topics on stackoverflow without success.

I've installed it with Homebrew.

git version 2.17.1 (Apple Git-112)

In terminal :

```
**Which Git**
-> /usr/bin/git

**sudo rm -f /usr/bin/git**
-> rm: /usr/bin/git: Operation not permitted
```

What the next step ?

Many thanks

Comment: EDIT : 
If I enter "rm" instead of "rm -f", I get this message : 
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for git?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1120240/operation-not-permitted-on-files-under-usr-bin

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title of a question. That's what an accepted answer is for :)

Comment: Isn’t git installed via Xcode? Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: In fact my real problem is about "git credential-osxkeychain". When I brew install 'formula'... the window pop and ask me for password. And I except that is the fault of git... After uninstall it... the issue is still there.

So yes... maybe it's the git version of Xcode and not the one installed with brew.

Comment: @jhpratt yes, I corrected that. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've figure out what to do : temporarily disable SIP
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

It's a pretty dangerous command...
Don't forget to re-enable directly after.

Comment: for that :
1. reboot and hold cmd+R
2. open terminal
3. enter : csrutil disable
4. enter : reboot
5. ...
6. reboot with cmd+R
7. open terminal
8. csrutil enable
9. reboot

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper `brew` command as indicated in the documentation (https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ):

```
brew uninstall --force git
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't installed `git` in another way?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher if it was installed through brew then `brew uninstall` command would have worked. git binary in `/usr/bin` comes with development tools but brew install put git binary in `/usr/local/bin/`